# Visual web part, SharePoint 2013 with VS 2012. Gridview with paging , export to excel

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

Created a visual web part for SharePoint 2013 with VS 2012 template. Web part has gridview with paging enable. On the same I have a button for export to excel. Gridview works perfect , but when I click "Export to Excel " that time gridview paging is not working unless I refresh my page. 
Export to Excel Code for reference

```
 private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = getListData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                Table table = new Table();
                if (GridView1.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    PrepareControlForExport(GridView1.HeaderRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(GridView1.HeaderRow);
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    PrepareControlForExport(row);
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                if (GridView1.FooterRow != null)
                {
                    PrepareControlForExport(GridView1.FooterRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(GridView1.FooterRow);
                }
                table.RenderControl(htw);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "SiteSize.xls"));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                //render the htmlwriter into the response
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of security setting of SharePoint. [Source](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/02/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-user-control-webpart.html)
I was able to figure out the issue and solution! All I've done is: added the OnClientClick to the button's event, and called the `_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;.`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" onclick="btnExportToExcel_Click" OnClientClick="_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;" />
```